# this pointer and all arguments are null after call (but ok before)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, ramcloud

I am having a strange problem I do not know how to debug:

I have the following (C++11) class method:

```
void RamCloud::write(uint32_t tableId, uint64_t id, const void* buf,
                     uint32_t length,
                     uint64_t* version, bool async)
{
    btree::node_cache& cache = btree::node_cache::instance(104857600);
        cache.write(tableId, id, buf, length);
    theCloud->write(tableId, id, buf, length, nullptr, version, async);
}
```

(don't thing too much what the code does, it does not really matter here).

Most of the time this works, but there is one case where it does fail. If I break at the last line using gdb, I can do the following:

```
(gdb) p theCloud
$3 = (RAMCloud::RamCloud *) 0x7fbe14009e90
(gdb) p tableId
$5 = 3
(gdb) p id
$6 = 3
(gdb) p buf
$7 = (const void *) 0x7fbe253a22d0
(gdb) p length
$8 = 31496
(gdb) p version
$9 = (uint64_t *) 0x0
(gdb) p async
$10 = false
(gdb) s
#0  0x00007fbe220344aa in RAMCloud::RamCloud::write (this=0x0, tableId=0, id=0, buf=0x0, length=0, rejectRules=0x0, version=0x0, async=false) at /local/mpilman/ramcloudarch/ramcloud/src/RamCloud.cc:260
(gdb) p this
$11 = (RAMCloud::RamCloud * const) 0x0
(gdb) p tableId
$12 = 0
(gdb) p id
$13 = 0
(gdb) p buf
$14 = (const void *) 0x0
(gdb) p length
$15 = 0
(gdb) p rejectRules 
$16 = (const RAMCloud::RejectRules *) 0x0
(gdb) p version
$17 = (uint64_t *) 0x0
(gdb) p async
$18 = false
```

So right before the call everything seems ok, but after the call, all arguments (including the this pointer) switch to null. When I try to continue I get of course a segfault...

So my question: what could be here the problem? The caller is in another library than the callee, but these libraries are linked statically (and everything is compiled with the same compiler).

gcc version is 4.6.1. Does anyone have an idea where I could start debugging?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is most likely caused by a bug in your code.

Comment: I know that. The question is where to start debugging if something like that happens (I never saw something similar before).

Comment: OK, I was being facetious. My point was that the problem is *elsewhere* in your code, and since you didn't post any of that, it's impossible for us to say anything meaningful beyond "debug it".

Comment: What level of optimization is being used? Is this one case reliably reproducible? If yes, is the caller causing the problem unique?

Comment: @KerrekSB: But the thing is: I have no idea where to start. So my proper question would be: how should I debug it? What could cause such a problem?

Comment: @dauphic: These are the compiler switches: "-Wall -Wno-unused-parameter    -std=c++0x -pipe -g -fPIC -O2 -g". I think for the static library (which contains the caller) the optimization is -O3. The bug is reliable reproducable - the stack trace and the arguments are always the same (but with other arguments it works a few time before the problem occurs).

Comment: It looks like your stack is being smashed; possibly something in the function tried to zero a buffer on the stack, but overran it. I would try using Valgrind or similar.

Comment: @MarkusPilman: Agreed with dauphic, `valgrind` is an excellent tool for discovering access errors, and it often reveals logic errors in your code.

Comment: @dauphic: You should change your "comment" to an "answer". (The question is "Does anyone have an idea where I could start debugging?", so "Try Valgrind!" is definitely a valid answer.)

Comment: @Markus:  You should rather edit the compiler switches into the question.  Anyway, the `-O2` may give you some problems with debugging, in that code and data may not be where you'd expect from the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your stack is being smashed. Tools like Valgrind on *nix or Application Verifier on Windows can be used to find the cause of these memory-related problems.

Comment: Stupid me, I wonder why I did not think about valgrind (I usually use it for memory leak detection and not for error detection - I need a shift in my thinking here). So I am now running my tests in Valgrind to see what happens here.